Pixel mapping to network inputs
I'm working with object detection models in embedded devices and need to run tests comparing performance on the embedded platform vs on a PC. For the integrity of the tests, I need to make sure the pixels are being mapped the same way in both cases. I understand how Pytorch turns images to tensors of shape CxHxW, but what I'm asking is exactly how do these pixels get mapped to the inputs. So, for example, does the top left pixel of the image (the values in all 3 channels) get assigned to the first input in a forward pass, or the last one?
